# torch7: Error in fine-tuning a CNN

Tags: lua, machine-learning, torch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to fine-tune a pre-trained **[OverFeat](https://github.com/jhjin/overfeat-torch)** conv-net (CNN) on a dataset of images of multi-class faces. My training-testing lua script is based on the tutorial given [here](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised).

I first created a script and tried to test my script by training-testing on a subset of the *ImageNet* dataset. After resolving some issues, it was working as expected without any errors. But, then I made slight changes to the script, like adding few layers in the neural net, changing the input files and labels, to adapt it to the new dataset. My updated model to be fine-tuned is as follows:

```
   net:add(SpatialConvolution(3, 96, 7, 7, 2, 2))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(96, 256, 7, 7, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(256, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(512, 512, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(512, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(1024, 1024, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(1024, 4096, 5, 5, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(4096, 4096, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(4096, 1000, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   -- net:add(nn.View(1000))
   net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
   net:add(SpatialConvolutionMM(1000, 530, 1, 1, 1, 1))
   net:add(nn.View(530))
   net:add(nn.SoftMax())
```

I am using **nn.ClassNLLCriterion()** to train my network. But upon training, I am facing the following error:

```
==> online epoch # 1 [batchSize = 8]    
/home/adarshc/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...shc/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ClassNLLCriterion.lua:38: attempt to call method 'type' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ...shc/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ClassNLLCriterion.lua:38: in function 'forward'
    final_2.lua:486: in function 'opfunc'
    /home/adarshc/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/sgd.lua:43: in function 'optimMethod'
    final_2.lua:509: in function 'train'
    final_2.lua:613: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...rshc/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I am unable to resolve it as I'm finding this error non-informative, and thus, difficult to trace and debug. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: includeu whole code yielding an error, together with sample data. Furthermore - in order to debug, reduce your network to something simple, you have 10 layers there! If there is any error in your parameters, it will be extremely hard to catch it, furthermore, such model will require LOTS of time to train, and it seems as one of your first approaches to it, you should never start from something this complex.

Comment: @lejlot, I am starting with this complexity because for my case, this is the simplest point to begin with. I could have included the whole code but it is large enough to simply quote it in a question. Also, since I am getting a compiler error, I thought that I was expecting some sort of common error(s) which I might be making. The more puzzling thing to me, which I have mentioned in the question itself, is the fact that I used almost the same procedure on a different dataset and it was working fine as expected. I just modified it a little bit to adapt it to the new dataset and I got the error.

Comment: No it is not. Having two conv layers would be enough to start and understand what is your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here when you do a [forward on your criterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/3585e82/ClassNLLCriterion.lua#L35-L42) the second argument (= target) has not the right type, hence this error.

Since you apparently work with mini-batches you are supposed to pass a 1D torch long tensor of size N = mini-batch size (in non batch mode it could be a `number` or a single element 1D long tensor).

*Note: at training time, right before the `nn.ClassNLLCriterion`, you should use a `nn.LogSoftMax()` and not a `nn.SoftMax()` layer. As an alternative there is a built-in layer that combines both: [`nn.CrossEntropyCriterion`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.CrossEntropyCriterion).*

Comment: deltheil, in my case, the classes/set of labels is a tensor of strings. Consequently, the labels in training and test files are strings. Should that be a problem? Because when I try to do `classes:type()`, I get the similar error of `attempt to call method 'type' (a nil value)` at this new added line. Here, `classes = require 'classes'`, where **classes.lua** is a file returning a tensor of labels as strings.

Comment: Each label (= target) must be a class index, i.e. a number between 1 and N where N = total number of classes (see [doc](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.ClassNLLCriterion)). As explained it could be a 1D tensor containing this number (or these numbers in batch mode). So yes working with string(s) or a tensor of string(s) is a problem.

Comment: deltheil, yes, you were right. I corrected my code by replacing the strings of class-names with their corresponding integer indexes (in files with the train-test labels) and my training procedure is working now. Thanks.